# How does routing work in polymer application

Tags: polymer-1.0

In Polymer applications, app-location  and app-route are used for page routing. The first line in the application has app-location component as below:

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
```

As I understand, the route="{{route}}" is used to bind the app-location route attribute to a "route" variable that is defined outside app-location component. It is the input to app-location.  Where is the "route" variable defined?

The documentation says:  the `app-location` produces a `route` value.
Does it mean that app-location creates a variable "route" in global name space and hence becomes available for other components to consume?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that the statement 
     
creates this.route variable that is available for the app.